# Reviewer stats in suggested edits should show improver

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Wouldn’t it be more useful to show the editor in addition to/in place of Community in the reviewer stats for a suggested edit?

[image: Screenshot of improved suggested edit with stats shown]

Comment: While we're at it, it should also show how many edits the user has improved in addition to approved and rejected.

Comment: @animuson: Yes, please. Also — is that stat even available anywhere?

Comment: I think the word should be "improvised". +1 to thought.

Comment: Not to mention that one reject vote stated too much change has occurred and the second reject vote states that edit was too minor.